# Is it possible to have not fully applied type-level functions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

Let's say we have the following input JSON data:

```json
{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": [2],
    "baz": [3],
}
```

Is it possible to convert this JSON to the following type:

```js
{
    foo: '1'
    bar: MyList<['2']>
    baz: MySet<['3']>
}
```

Based on the following data:

```js
{
    foo: new MyType<string>(),
    bar: new MyType<MyList<string[]>>(),
    baz: new MyType<MySet<string[]>>(),
}
```

The conversion from `number` to `string` of the number literals is just to indicate I plan to do some transformation there (though the actual types in my use case are more complex).

I can get it to work to some degree with hardcoding the container types, e.g. `MyList`:

```js
const input = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: [2],
    baz: [3],
} as const;
type Input = typeof input;

class MyType<T> {}
type MyList<T> = Array<T>;
type MySet<T> = Set<T>;

const data = {
    foo: new MyType<string>(),
    bar: new MyType<MyList<string[]>>(),
    baz: new MyType<MySet<string[]>>(),
};
type Data = typeof data;

type ToString<N extends number> = `${N}`;

const result = {} as {
    [K in keyof Input]: [Input[K], Data[K]] extends [infer I, MyType<infer T>]
        ? T extends string
            ? I extends number
                ? ToString<I>
                : never
            : T extends MyList<string[]>
            ? I extends readonly number[]
                ? MyList<number[]>
                : never
            : T extends MySet<string[]>
            ? I extends readonly number[]
                ? MySet<number[]>
                : never
            : never
        : never;
};
// const result: {
//     readonly foo: "1";
//     readonly bar: MyList<number[]>;
//     readonly baz: MySet<number[]>;
// }
```

Would it be possible to retain the literal tuple and without hardcoding the container types?

With my current code, not hardcoding would just be a matter of (assuming safety is ensured through other means):

```js
const result = {} as {
    [K in keyof Input]: [Input[K], Data[K]] extends [infer I, MyType<infer T>]
        ? T extends string
            ? I extends number
                ? ToString<I>
                : never
            : T
        : never;
};
// const result: {
//     readonly foo: "1";
//     readonly bar: MyList<number[]>;
//     readonly baz: MySet<number[]>;
// }
```

If I could pass to `MyType` a type-level function that got as its argument the literal, it would be easy to implement these container types. However I have no idea if this is at all possible in TypeScript or if there are some other ways around it to get the intended result.

Comment: Higher kinded types are not possible in TypeScript, but maybe this [blog post](https://www.matechs.com/blog/encoding-hkts-in-typescript-once-again) will give you some ideas.

Comment: That blog post is a wonderful lead and seems to be the missing piece of what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comment of @kelly pointing me towards a [blog post](https://www.matechs.com/blog/encoding-hkts-in-typescript-once-again) explaining a trick to emulate higher kinded types to some degree, I managed to get it to work as intended.

The trick described in the blog post is the following:

```js
interface IdFunction {
    readonly input: unknown
    readonly output: this['input']
}
type X = (IdFunction & { readonly input: 5 })['output']
// type X = 5
```

Using it, the type of the input can be given at a later point, making it act like a type-level function that still expects arguments.

The key insight is that `this` refers to the final type (in this case `IdFunction & { readonly input: 5 }`, that resolves to `{ readonly input: 5; readonly output: this['input'] }`), making it possible to have multiple subtypes, yet when accessing them through the `output` property of the parent type, it will still provide the information given in the subtype.

Given the example provided in my question, here is a full example of this trick being applied:

```js
const input = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: [2],
    baz: [3],
} as const;
type Input = typeof input;

type NumberToString<N extends number> = `${N}`;
type NumbersToStrings<T extends readonly [...any[]]> = T extends readonly [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Head extends number
        ? [NumberToString<Head>, ...NumbersToStrings<Tail>]
        : [...NumbersToStrings<Tail>]
    : [];

class MappedType {
    readonly A: unknown;
    readonly B: unknown;
}
class MappedList extends MappedType {
    readonly A: [...number[]];
    readonly B: MyList<NumbersToStrings<this['A']>>;
}
class MappedSet extends MappedType {
    readonly A: [...number[]];
    readonly B: MySet<NumbersToStrings<this['A']>>;
}

class MyType<T> {}
type MyList<T> = Array<T>;
type MySet<T> = Set<T>;

const data = {
    foo: new MyType<string>(),
    bar: new MyType<MappedList>(),
    baz: new MyType<MappedSet>(),
};
type Data = typeof data;

const result = {} as {
    [K in keyof Input]: [Input[K], Data[K]] extends [infer I, MyType<infer T>]
        ? T extends string
            ? I extends number
                ? NumberToString<I>
                : never
            : T extends MappedType
            ? (T & { readonly A: I })['B']
            : never
        : never;
};
// const result: {
//     readonly foo: "1";
//     readonly bar: MyList<["2"]>;
//     readonly baz: MySet<["3"]>;
// }
```